# How to click in button inside shadow Cypress.io

Tags: html, cypress, shadow-dom

I'm using cypress.io and I need to click in a button inside a shadow-root.

[image: Code HTML]

I need to click in Yes button.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you add what have you tried so far and what error are you getting or what is happening when you try to click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use **button text** rather than classes to select the button you want.

The same class `.buttons-confirmation` appears on both buttons, so when you select it you will get both buttons.

```
cy.get('base-confirmation')
  .shadow()
  .contains('button', 'Yes')
  .click();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply add `{ "includeShadowDom" : true }` to your cypress.json file along with other properties and click the element as clicking a regular element[image]

```
cy.get('base-confirmation')
  .contains('button', 'Yes')
  .click();
```

Comment: with recent versions of cypress `cypress.json` is now `cypress.config.js`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.shadow()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/shadow.html) to traverse through a shadow dom and perform actions on your desired element.

If you want to click *Yes* button:

```
cy.get('base-confirmation')
  .shadow()
  .find('.modal-content')
  .find('.content-confirmation')
  .find('.base-confirmation')
  .find('.buttons-confirmation')
  .click()
```

If you want to click *No* button:

```
cy.get('base-confirmation')
  .shadow()
  .find('.modal-content')
  .find('.content-confirmation')
  .find('.base-confirmation')
  .find('.buttons-confirmation.cancelBtn')
  .click()
```

Comment: Good answer, but in Yes button you need to choose the button Yes. Because you have 2 buttons.